# How to lowercase only HTML elements

Tags: php, regex

How can I lowercase all HTML elements but not their attributes or attribute values?

I found a lot of examples like

```
$newString = preg_replace("/<[^>]+>/e", "strtolower('\\0')", $oldString);
```

But it lower cases everything, not just the tags.

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need to maintain the attribute name's case? The spec states they are to be case-insensitive. http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/structure.html#attributes

Comment: This is for HTML-like code that's being passed to a PDF generation system, it's not for web standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`$newString = preg_replace( "/<([^> ]+)/e", "strtolower('\\0')", $oldString )`

Comment: But if the HTML is `<P CLASS="aSa">X<-Y<-Z</P>` it will output `<p CLASS="aSa">X<-y<-z</p>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$newString = preg_replace("/</?\w+/e", "strtolower('\\0')", $oldString);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$oldString = "<H1 CLASS='abc'>HGKJHG</H1>\n< P ClAsS='AbC123'>HKJGHG</P>";
$newString = preg_replace("~(</?\s*\w+)~e", "strtolower('\\1')", $oldString); 
echo $newString,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<h1 CLASS='abc'>HGKJHG</h1>
< p ClAsS='AbC123'>HKJGHG</p>
```

Comment: But if the HTML is `<P CLASS="aSa">X<_Y <-Z</P>` it will output `<p CLASS="aSa">X<_y <-Z</p>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_case_tags($string, $action = 'mb_strtolower')
{
    $string = preg_replace('!<([^> ]+)!e', "$action('\\0')", $string);

    if(strpos($string, '=') !== false)
    {
        return $string = preg_replace('!(?:\s([^\s]+)=([\'"])?(.+)\\2)!Uie', "$action(' \\1').'='.str_replace('\\\\\\', '', '\\2').'\\3'.str_replace('\\\\\\', '', '\\2').''", $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```