# How to convert HTML <TAGS> to <tags> in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a lot of HTML data to import which uses uppercase tag and attribute names. Unfortunately the receiving system does not allow this, insisting that they are all lower case.

How can I safely change all the tags and attribute names?

I would jump to a regular expression preg_replace_callback, but I know that can end up really tricky when it comes to parsing HTML - kind of reinventing the wheel.

Is there a DOMDocument or other safer solution?

Comment: Try using DOMDocument to just load the HTML and then immediately save it. See if that works.

Comment: Try this `/<\([^>]*\)>/<\L\1>/g` regular expression refer: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_all_HTML_tags_to_lowercase

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229795/convert-all-html-tags-to-lowercase , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732628/how-to-lowercase-only-html-elements , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326880/converting-uppercase-html-tags-to-lowercase

Comment: @hutchbat please link to one that includes attributes, and does not contain deprecated code (/e modifier), and as question states, I'd prefer to avoid pitfalls of regex for parsing HTML, something which many existing answers mention but do not offer a solution to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @niet suggested, you can try to use `DOMDocument` then save it and try to output it.

Consider this example:

```
<?php

$html_with_uppercase_tags = '<BODY><DIV class="container"><H1>Headers</H1><P>This is paragraph one</P></DIV></BODY>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_with_uppercase_tags);

echo htmlentities($dom->saveHTML()); // check the tags
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

?>
```

Should yield something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <html><body><div class="container"><h1>Headers</h1><p>This is paragraph one</p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to extract this without the `<!DOCTYPE` and `<html><body>` wrappers? Obv. I can regexp it, but just wondering...

Comment: @artfulrobot yes i though you'll ask about this one, thats why i added the a link inside my answers, the comments there did'nt like the function appending the doctype, visit the link, by the way, it automatically appends it when you use this functions, you can only use workarounds